# How to flash mobject between two colors

Tags: manim

I want to define a Animation which change color of a mobject between two colors during specific time period.

E.g. a mobject with color RED, I want to set its color between RED and YELLOW back and forth 5 times during 2 seconds.

Below is my code (can change color, but the interval is not even）, just want to confirm whether it is the correct way to do this, thanks!:

```
class ChangeColor(Animation):
    def interpolate_submobject(self, submobject, starting_sumobject, alpha):
        m = int(alpha * 10) % 2
        if m == 0:
            submobject.set_color(RED)
        else:
            submobject.set_color(YELLOW)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `alpha` increment is `smooth`, so you have to change it to `linear` so that it is displayed correctly.

```py
class ChangeColor(Animation):
    CONFIG={
        "rate_func":linear
    }
    def interpolate_submobject(self, submobject, starting_sumobject, alpha):
        m = int(alpha * 10) % 2
        if m == 0:
            submobject.set_color(RED)
        else:
            submobject.set_color(YELLOW)
```